# Generate Stored Procedure Script for a Given input value - For Debugging

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My stored procedure runs multiple queries inline. I would like to have my input values replaced into the stored procedure for debugging.

I am taking a simple example below. I would like to call this script `myScript`

eg.

```
myScript MyProcedure Abc, 123, 99999
```

returns

```
select id from fooTable where name = 'Abc' and value > 123 and value < 99999
```

Comment: Unclear what you wish to do? You already have the sp? you just have to pass different value as parameters!

Comment: @Nadeem_MK I wish to have the variable names replaced with the values provided within the procedure and have it run

Comment: Then you can simply set the values inside the sp;
`SET 1stParam = 'Your value'`

Comment: @Nadeem_MK there are over 10 parameters and I am hoping that there is a an easier way to get queries with these values replaced. Some of it is also simple arithmetic

Comment: I don't think there is any simpler way. Either you pass the parameters from the caller or you hardcode it and set them inside the sp. :)

Comment: Do you know you can construct a stored procedure that receives parameter, right? You can use two stored procedures: a caller one that would call another one changing the parameters, using a loop for example (or even joining another table). Is that what you want?

Comment: @DLNarasimhan are you saying that you want to know if you can use a procedure to show you the output of a dynamic sql statement?